# jdtls failing to start for lsp-java after clearing .m2/repository

Tags: lsp-mode

I have `lsp-java` set up to use `jdtls`.  It had been working fairly well.  For unrelated reasons, I deleted my ~/.m2/repository and then reran `mvn install` to repopulate the parts of it that I need.

Now when I try to start the LSP server, it fails:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Users/me/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.22/lombok-1.18.22.jar

Process jdtls stderr finished
```

I know that I had previously been working on project that use Lombok 1.18.22, but the only one I am currently working on uses 1.18.26.  I am confident that somewhere, there is a file listing all the projects I've worked on and `lsp-java` is trying to load all the jars I've needed so that they are available.

I am confident that I could fix this specific problem by downloading that jar, but there could easily be another dozen jars that I don't use any more, and I'd rather not go around building old projects until everything works.

I already tried deleting what looked like cache directories (~/.emacs.d/var/lsp and lsp-java), but that just forced me to reinstall `jdtls` without resolving the problem.

What do I need to do to clear out that history?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check [lsp-java issues](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java/issues) for ideas or try [lsp-mode troublshooting](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/troubleshooting/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in the past, I had customized `lsp-java-vmargs`

to include

```
"-javaagent:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.22/lombok-1.18.22.jar"
```

That was the source that I was unable to find.

Updating that to 1.18.26 (both the directory and the file name) fixed the problem.

Answering this so that the next person this happens (which could be me when I replace this laptop in a few years) knows to check there, since I had completely forgotten that the variable existed or that I had customized it.